# Where does XCode Console App Build Go?

Tags: xcode, macos, console

Where does the build output go for a console app?  I can run the app from within XCode, but I want to try and run it form the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you right-click on the [target](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Targets.html) application under the 'products' folder you should be given a context menu. Select 'Show in Finder'.

The '[target](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Targets.html)' application is the application which you're targeting to build. As you can see, right clicking on this displays the 'Show in Finder' option

[image]

Comment: right click where? What is the target application. What Products directory?

Comment: and btw: Selecting 'Show in Finder' doesn't work in xcode 7.0

Comment: @CJohnson, It works just fine for me on XCode 7.0.1. I've updated the answer, so there's no need to down-vote due to your lack of understanding Apple's terminology!

Comment: thanks for updating the answer. btw, some of us are very new to apple and it's dev tools.

Comment: @CJohnson, being new to a technology is not a problem, we're here to help ;O)

Answer (score -1):

Open the project. 
In the project directory, select the project navigator. 
It should show some folders for your source files, as well as two at the end called 'Frameworks' and 'Products'. 
Double click the 'Products' Folder to expand it.
There should be an entry under it called foo.app. Where foo is the name of your project.
Select the entry for foo.app.

In the attribute editor look at the top. There is an entry called: 'Full Path'. It should point to the full path of your application.

For instance: `/Users/myself/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InternationalMountains-gxduphnptzmjqsbmpnqxhxansikq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/InternationalMountains.app`